# Can't resolve URL until program is restarted

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, dns

I've got a python script that basically looks something like this:

```
#############################
# MAIN LOOP
while True:
        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        try:
            client_socket.connect((url, socketnum))
            packet = somedata
            client_socket.sendall(packet)

        except Exception as e:
            # an error occurred
            logging.error("An error occurred: {}".format(e))
            pass
        finally:
            logging.info("Closing socket...")
            client_socket.close()

    time.sleep(70)
```

What I find is that if this script is run before an internet connection is established on the computer (an embedded Linux system), naturally, when the socket tries to connect, I get "Errno -3 Temporary failure in name resolution". However, if the internet connection is then established, the program STILL cannot resolve the hostname - the only way to get it to work is to restart the python script.

Since this system is not one where I can guarantee the presence of an internet connection at all times, is there anyway to get python to realise that the internet connection now exists and that name resolution information is now available?

**EDIT:** Some further testing shows that this only happens if the python program is started before any successful internet connection is established on the machine after a boot up. If the python program is started AFTER an internet connection has previously been established on the machine (even if it's subsequently been disconnected), the program operates correctly and will successfully connect to the internet after internet connectivity is restored.

So:

Bootup->Python started->Internet connection established = program doesn't work

Bootup->Internet connection established->Internet disconnected->Python started = program works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing DNS cache in every iteration.

```
import os
... 
while True:
    os.popen('nscd -I hosts',"r")
...
```

or try `service nscd restart` command instead.